# Django @login_required is not working

Tags: django

I learn login Authentication in django and use @login_required decorator to prevent person does not see the page content before login but it not working.

view.py

```
from django.contrib.auth.decorators import login_required

@login_required
def dashboard(request):
    return render(request, 'login/dashboard.html')
```

urls.py

```
app_name='login'
urlpatterns=[
    # html urls
    url(r'^$',views.index),
    url(r'^login_form/$',views.login_form),
    url(r'^dashboard/$',views.dashboard),
    url(r'^profile/$',views.profile),
    url(r'^logout/$',views.logout),
]
```

setting.py

```
LOGIN_URL = '/login_form/'
```

dashboard.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Dashboard</title>
</head>
<body>
{% verbatim %}
<h1>Username: {{ username }}</h1>
<h1>Token: {{ token }}</h1>
<button type="button" class="" ng-click="logout()">logout</button>
{% endverbatim %}

<a href="#profile">see profile</a>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: What does "not working" entail? errors? are you sure you aren't logged in?

Comment: it did not show any error. I am sure i am not logged in.

Comment: Check that you are not logged in via admin. That also counts as a login

Comment: Following on Moses's answer, do you see a username in the first <h1>?
Otherwise, make sure that 'django.contrib.auth' is in the INSTALLED_APPS

Comment: opss! thanks alot you save my day. @Moses Koledoye

Comment: but i am confuse if admin is login why its not show there name and token?

Comment: `return render(request, 'login/dashboard.html')` -> because you do not send `usename` and `token` to template. They are not falling from the sky :)

Comment: @trantu - The verbatim tag surrounding it would indicate they're angular variables and not django ones, I removed the angular tag because it wasn't relevant to the questions problem.